# Build a Task Management App using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, erp, task-management

I am looking to build a Order Management and Task Management App for my company. I am a beginner in Programming and know only Javascript (Can manage with HTML and CSS ) . This app would also require to connect with a database. Is it possible to build it only using Javascript (without the use of any other languages like PHP etc) and is it advisable. Is there any other more feasible solution.

If Javascript will suffice, a few more queries in the same line

1. What database would be the best to use ?
2. Would using Angular JS help ?
3. How do I search and use if theres a similar project in Github that runs only on Javascript ?

Comment: Nodejs (Javascript)
AngularJS (Javascript )
Mysql Backend

Answer (score 1):

1. suggest [you read more about the MEAN stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)), it's a very popular stack that let you build the whole stack (DB, Server side logic, Client Side logic) with Javascript alone.

in short:

> - MongoDB, a NoSQL database
> - Express.js, a web application framework that runs on Node.js
> - Angular.js, a JavaScript MVC framework that runs in browser    JavaScript engines
> - Node.js, an execution environment for event-driven server-side and    networking applications

2. using the angular JS is optional in my opinion, it is required if you want to make it to feel as single page app.
3. [try this on github](https://github.com/hwz/chirp), an example for MEAN stack.

Comment: mean.js or mean.io - Whats best ? And I have never worked on any frameworks except for WAMP . How difficult do you think is this if you only know Javascript and HTML

Answer (score 0):

You have to Choose

- Nodejs Server (Javascript)
- AngularJS Client  (Javascript )
- Mysql Backend

They are More Flexible with friendly Solutions

Comment: Hello Vicky, Can you please advise me how do I setup an environment for Angular and node with Mysql as database .. Will Wamp work ?

Comment: Its Pretty cool if u use Wamp server ,See this link  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hh0eUrbdcNY ,or  See this tutorial https://trinitytuts.com/node-js-express-connectivity-with-phpmyadmin/   then Just include angularjs and start your node application ... :) Happy Coding

Comment: Is MEAN not advisable ? Is it difficult to adapt mongo db as a beginner programmer ? I feel i would get more support if I use MEAN than using Node, angular and mysql combination as very few ppl are using it. What do u you suggest ?

Comment: Why not MEAN , Why not (MySql ,Nodejs,Angularjs) its depending on our choice .... Apart from that  php , nodejs , java  Supporting mysql ... U can get more support from mysql ... your every question will be answered ...

Comment: This is my first project .. I have only learnt Javascript ...and trying to learn AngularJS and I know considerable HTML and CSS.. Would you like to collaborate and help me execute this project ?

Comment: OK , Don't worry , Start from AngularJs , Because if u know angularJs Then u can do anything from it ... See Plnkr examples . and Js Fiddle , Any    Doubt u can ask me ...

Comment: Thanks Bro for the awesome support.Truly appreciate that.

Comment: Is there another way I can remain in touch with you ?

Comment: Yes , We can communicate through email ...

Answer (score 0):

You could build and host your app on something like https://firebase.google.com/ - build the entire thing in eg polymer and let google host it, that way you'd be building the thing entirely in JS, no other language required